# How to create continuous Marquee of multiple images from bottom to top without stopping any image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m looking to create a border of one mobile friendly html page where I need both right and left side of mobile screen to have multiple color images to move from bottom to top very smoothly and without showing a gap once the queue is completed. The joint should be invisible to find. It can be something like chain or track of a tank. Constantly moving if you see tank moving from top view.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Please post some code showing what you have so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for CSS animations with `@keyframes`. Work through the tutorial below, but note that instead of `translateX()`, you will need to use `translateY()`.

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/